# "Such as me" or "such as myself" — which one is correct?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, personal-pronouns, comparisons, reflexives

Which is correct, "such as myself" or "such as me"?

Comment: It entirely depends on what you are saying. Many contexts would allow for either, but if you can give us an example of a sentence we can comment more precisely.

Answer (score 3):

Either. *Such as myself* is perhaps more emphatic.

There are people who insist on *such as I* (on the specious justification that the phrase represents *such as I am*). Hardly anybody *says* this, but it is always acceptable in formal contexts.

Answer (score 2):

"Myself" is a Reflexive pronoun, so it should be used as a Direct or Indirect Object. The wording of "Such as myself" specifies a non-reflexive pronoun, so we can narrow it down to "Such as I" or "Such as me."

"Such as I/me" is an abbreviation for 'Such a person as I am." So, in order to choose between Such as I and Such as me, we should change it to the long version to check.

"Such a person as me am." That doesn't work at all.
"Such a person as I am." That does work. Therefore, you shouldn't use *either* of those, but instead use "Such as I."

Comment: Nonsense. This argument was always false: there is no reason whatever to regard _such as me_ as an abbreviation for anything, since _as_ is a perfectly good preposition. The most you can say is that there are some people who will insist on _such as I_.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have worded that as, "if you regard Such as I as an abbreviation." This is because the origin of Such as I is Such a person as I am. Even if it weren't (but I believe it is) Such a person as I am is still a valid replacement for Such as I, just a bit longer. This is why I made that argument.

Comment: Yes, but the question was about _such as me_ and _such as myself_, which are a different construction. Most of your answer is irrelevant to the question, and ends up with a bald statement which is wrong.

Comment: I see. I concede. I'll do some more research on this and possibly get back to you.